# Multi threaded embedded linux application state machine design

Tags: c, linux, embedded, embedded-linux

Problem definition:

We are designing an application for an industrial embedded system running Linux.

The system is driven by events from the outside world. The inputs to the system could be any of the following:

1. Few inputs to the system in the form of Digital IO lines(connected
   to the GPIOs of the processor like e-stop).
2. The system runs a web-server which allows for the system to be
   controlled via the web browser.
3. The system runs a TCP server. Any PC or HMI device could send commands over TCP/IP.

The system needs to drive or control RS485 slave devices over UART using Modbus. The system also need to control few IO lines like Cooler ON/OFF etc.We believe that a state machine is essential to define this application. The core application shall be a multi threaded application which shall have the following threads...

1. Main thread
2. Thread to control the RS485 slaves.
3. Thread to handle events from the Web interface.
4. Thread to handle digital I/O events.
5. Thread to handle commands over TCP/IP(Sockets)

For inter-thread communication, we are using Pthread condition signal & wait.  As per our initial design approach(one state machine in main thread), any input event to the system(web or tcp/ip or digital I/O) shall be relayed to the main thread and it shall communicate to the appropriate thread for which the event is destined. A typical scenario would be to get the status of the RS485 slave through the web interface. In this case, the web interface thread shall relay the event to the main thread which shall change the state and then communicate the event to the thread that control's the RS485 slaves & respond back. The main thread shall send the response back to the web interface thread.

Questions:

1. Should each thread have its own state machine thereby reducing the
   complexity of the main thread ? In such a case, should we still need
   to have a state machine in main thread ?
2. Any thread processing input event can communicate directly to the
   thread that handles the event bypassing the main thread ? For e.g
   web interface thread could communicate directly with the thread
   controlling the RS485 slaves ?
3. Is it fine to use pthread condition signals & wait for inter thread
   communication or is there a better approach ?
4. How can we have one thread wait for event from outside & response
   from other threads ? For e.g. the web interface thread usually waits
   for events on a POSIX message queue for Inter process communication
   from web server CGI bins. The CGI bin's send events to the web
   interface thread through this message queue. When processing this
   event, the web interface thread would wait for response from other
   threads. In such a situation, it couldn't process any new event from
   the web interface until it has completed processing the previous
   event and gets back to the wait on the POSIX message queues.

sorry for the too big explanation...I hope I have put forward my explanation in the best possible way for others to understand and help me.

I could give more inputs if needed.

Comment: It seems that the approach described in the original question re-invents the active object (actor) design pattern. I would recommend taking a look at the open source QP active object framework (http://www.state-machine.com/qp). There is a port of this framework to POSIX with p-threads at http://www.state-machine.com/linux.

Comment: Sure Mr.Miro, I would look into that option...thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

What I always try to do with such requirements is to use one state machine, run by one 'SM' thread, which could be the main thread.  This thread waits on an 'EventQueue' input producer-cosumer queue with a timeout.  The timeout is used to run an internal delta-queue that can provide timeout events into the state-machine when they are required.

All other threads communicate their events to the state engine by pushing messages onto the EventQueue, and the SM thread processes them serial manner.

If an action routine in the SM decides that it must do something, it must not synchronously wait for anything and so it must request the action by pushing a request message to an input queue of whatever thread/susbsystem can perform it.

My message class, (OK, *struct in your C case), typically contains a 'command' enum, 'result' enum, a data buffer pointer, (in case it needs to transport bulk data), an error-message pointer, (null if no error), and as much other state as is necessary to allow the asynchronous queueing up of any kind of request and returning the complete result, (whether success or fail).

This message-passing, one SM design is the only one I have found that is capable of doing such tasks in a flexible, expandable manner without entering into a nightmare world of deadlocks, uncontrolled communications and unrepeatable, undebuggable interactions.

The first question that should be asked about any design is 'OK, how can the system be debugged if there is some strange problem?'.  In my design above, I can answer straightaway: 'we log all events dequeued in the SM thread - they all come in serially so we always know exactly what actions are taken based on them'.  If any other design is suggested, ask the above question and, if a good answer is not immediately forthcoming, it will never be got working.

So:

1. If a thread, or threaded subsystem, can use a separate state-machine to do its own INTERNAL functionality, OK, fine.  These SM's should be invisible from the rest of the system.
2. NO!
3. Use the pthread condition signals & wait to implement producer-consumer blocking queues.
4. One input queue per thread/subsystem.  All inputs go to this queue in the form of messages. Commands/state in each message identify the message and what should be done with it.

BTW, I would 100% do this in C++ unless shotgun-at-head :)

Comment: Mr.Martin James,I will consider all the points you have mentioned. I will have to do some work and then get back to you with the new design. Thank you..

Comment: @Martin James, I have a few clarifications in your design approach.If the main state machine or the main thread is going to asynchronously dispatch input events to subsystem threads, how the main thread get the result as the main thread would be busy waiting for for input events.  Also I couldn't understand about the internal delta queue that you have mentioned ? Could you please elaborate on that ?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a legacy embedded library that was originally written for a clone (`EC115/EC270`) of `Siemens ES122C` terminal controller. This library and OS included more or less what you describe. The original hardware was based on 80186 cpu. The OS, `RMOS` for Siemens, `FXMOS` for us (don't google it was never published) had all the stuff needed for basic controller work.
It had preemptive multi-tasking, task-to-task communication, semaphores, timers and I/O events, but no memory protection.
I ported that stuff to RaspberryPi (i.e. Linux).

I used the pthreads to simulate our legacy "tasks" because we hadn't memory protection, so threads are semantically the closest. 
The rest of the implementation then turned around the `epoll` API. This means that everything generates an event. An event is when something happens, a timer expires, another thread sends data, a TCP socket is connected, an IO pin changes state, etc. 
This requires that all the event sources be transformed in file descriptors. Linux provides several syscalls that do exactly that:
for task to task communication I used classic Unix pipes.
for timer events I used `timerfd` API.
for TCP communication I used normal sockets.
for serial I/O I simply opened the right device `/dev/???`.
signals are not necessary in my case but Linux provides 'signalfd' if necessary.

I have then `epoll_wait` wrapped around to simulate the original semantic.

I works like a charm.

TL;DR

take a deep look at the `epoll` API it does what you probably need.

EDIT: Yes and the advices of Martin James are very good especially 4. Each thread should only ever be in a loop waiting on an event via epoll_wait.